# Why java.util.Set does not contain value getter? Are there alternatives to it?

Tags: java, collections

As set entries are distinguished only by a subset of properties (`hashCode()` + `equals()`), there is sometimes a need to operate on original object contained in a set, which is not possible with `java.util.Set`. The only alternative I came up with is: `Map<T, T>` - not a very concise solution.

Are there any other alternatives in collections framework? Requirements are: O(1) fetch time and no duplicates based on `hashCode() + equals()` result.

Comment: Are you looking for [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)?

Comment: Ah, so you want the original object from the Set. Well, the easiest way would be your Map<T,T> solution. Is there a reason why it's not very handy?

Comment: @Kayaman - right, fixed

Comment: @DhrubajyotiGogoi - HashSet is just an implementation of Set

Comment: @assylias I cannot fetch original value from set in O(1) time. Can I?

Comment: @Marcin No, that's why you need a HashMap. That's the other hash-based collection in the standard API. And this is the solution with the least effort. Not a very pretty solution, but you don't have very pretty requirements :|

Comment: @Marcin May be I was not able to understand your problem. But with HashSet you have both constant time retrieval for basic operations and since it is backed by sets it will not allow duplicates (based on hashCode() and equals()). Doesn't that solve your problem?

Comment: @DhrubajyotiGogoi try to extract original object from `HashSet`. This is what I would like to do.

Comment: @Marcin You mean a sort of pool so that when you need a new instance of your object you first check if a similar one (equals + hashcode) already exists in the collection and use that one if it is the case?

Comment: @Marcin You will retrieve the same object you had put in.

Comment: @Marvin: Which object do you want to retrieve from the set? A set may contain many objects and since a set has no defined order, a `get(int index)` method does not make sense.

Comment: @Marcin How do you plan to retrieve the original object? By some key, object with identical properties or the original object itself or anything else?

Comment: A `Map<T, T>` is the _right solution._

Comment: (Also, FWIW, a `HashMap<T, T>` won't take any more memory than a `HashSet<T>`, and will be exactly as efficient.  Seriously.)

Comment: I don't really get purpose of the access. You try to access you already know (as hashCode() + equals() are the same) - for the sake of curiosity, could you kindly explain what is that needed for?

Answer (score 2):

If one more O(1) operation is not problem, you can **simulate** absenting method `get(Object)` with pair of methods `set.remove(Object)` and `set.add(Object)`. Otherwise, I would use `Map<T,T>` as you mentioned or simple **wrapper class** with underlying map.

**EDIT**: The reason why `Set` doesn't contain `get(Object)` is that you don't need to return object which you know. You just need to check, if your object is contained in set or not.

Answer (score 0):

Not in `java.util.Collections` itself, but using [Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), you can retrieve any element from a given `Iterator` using [`Iterables.get`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#get%28java.lang.Iterable,%20int%29).

Normally I would not advocate external libraries, but given how extremely powerful and useful Guava is, I see no problem with it.

Alternatively you could just iterate the set with your own implementation.

---

Additionally I found a very interesting [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303875/how-to-find-and-return-objects-in-java-hashset) on here that explains this behaviour.

Comment: But it wouldn't be O(1) anymore.

Answer (score 0):

A `Set` cannot contain two objects `o1` and `o2` such that `o1.equals(o2`) (No `hashCode` is used in this criteria).

A `HashSet` is using a hashmap to store its objects efficiently so eventually a HashMap is exactly what you need for `hashCode()+equals()` based operations.

Comment: That's not what he's asking for: he wants to retrieve an object from a set that `equals` another object in constant time.

Comment: @arshajii I understand that, but the Set interface does not provide a get method for retrieval of objects and its probably since this is not the intention of a Set. His requirement of efficiently  distinguishing objects by using their hashcode and equals is exactly what Hash Maps are for.

Comment: So you're saying he should use a `Map<T, T>`, as he already attempted?

Comment: This really depends on what he means by original object. Does it refers to the same instance created (memory-wise) or just an object with the exact same properties. For the latter he can safely use a Hashmap. And I would really like to what is the need for the same exact instance if such is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote such a class if you want to reuse it. [Jayes](https://github.com/kutschkem/Jayes) contains a class `org.eclipse.recommenders.jayes.util.sharing.CanonicalSet` that allows retrieval based on pretty much any equivalence relation that you can encode in a `hashCode()` and `equals()` implementation. I used it to build array equivalence classes. You can look at those implementations of `CanonicalSet`, they are in the same package.

Oh, but yeah, it's also just based on a `Map<Entry<T>,T>`, so nothing magical really.

Answer (score 0):

The code for a HashSet based on a HashMap is super simple: if you look at the way it's implemented in the JDK, there are very few lines of *actual* code (ignoring the constructors and the serialiazation code).

On way to do it would be to implement your own version of HashSet with the additional `get()` method

```
public E get(Object o) {
   return map.get(o);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SetUniqueList](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections//javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/list/SetUniqueList.html) from [commons-collections](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/)

It Decorates a `java.util.List` to ensure that no duplicates are present much like a `java.util.Set`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a bit of pain, not being able to **share** equal objects. The problem with the Set API, that ther is missing a specific addAndGet:

```
AddOnceSet<String> set = new AddOnceSet<>();
String s = in.readLine();
s = set.addOnce(s); // The new s is equal, and identical to the first added one.

s = set.getOnce(s);
```

Unfortunately this does not fit the collections API. I wish this could be in Java 8+.
In Java 8 you could add an Interface with defaults for `addOnce` and `getOnce`.

Implementation like you said, in:

```
private Map<T, T> sharedThings = new HashMap<>().

public T shareThing(T s) {
    String t = sharedThings.get(s);
    if (t == null) {
        t = s;
        sharedStrings.put(t, t);
    }
    return t;
}

...

public void setT(T t) {
    this.t = sharedThing(t);
}
```